# Constraint to allow assigning nil to a field of generic type in Go

Tags: go, generics, interface

In Go, I want to assign a field of generic type T of a struct to nil, are there any constraints I can add to T to make it work? For example:

```
type Foo[T ...] struct {
    value T
}

func (f *Foo[T ...]) assignNil() {
    f.value = nil // expect this to work
}

type Interface interface {}
```

I want to do this in case `Interface` became type paremeter when instantiating an instance of `Foo`

Comment: There's no way to express a "nil-able" type constraint in Go. However, you can always set `f.value` to the zero value of type `T`.

Comment: Oh thank you, setting f.value to the zero value of type T solves my problem

Answer (score -1):

You cannot as T might not be "nil-able" (nil might not be a valid value for T), e.g. in Foo[string].

Comment: I know that those are the cases, but is there any constraints to T we can add to make that work @Volker?